# Enforce uniqueness on sublevel in XML-file

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, key

I am trying to enforce uniqueness on a sublevel in an xml-schema, but I have problem formulating the xpath expression to enforce this.

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <id></id>
        <level2>
            <id></id>
        <level2>
            <id></id>
        <level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

In essence, what I want to do is to make sure that id is unique within level1, not just level 2.

I have tried several different xpath expressions in the key definition, but it either cant be compiled, or validates an obviously incorrect XML, meaning my key definition is incorrect or at least not doing what I want it to do.

```
<xs:key name="ID">
    <xs:selector xpath="level1"/>
    <xs:field xpath="//ID"/>
</xs:key>
```

My understanding is that the selector sets the scope, and field is used to identify the element that has to be unique. According to my very basic understanding of Xpath, // ought to match any ID regardless of where it is in the structure, but the above definition is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The `field` field of `key`s only accepts a subset of XPath according to [the XSD RFC](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-c-fields-xpaths) :

> `Path    ::=      ('.' '//')? ( Step '/' )* ( Step | '@' NameTest )`

It looks like `//selector` (which would mean anywhere in the current document) isn't accepted, but `.//selector` (meaning anywhere in the current context) could be used.

Comment: I have tried `<xs:field xpath=".//ID"/>` and `<xs:field xpath="./level2/ID"/>` which both are valid, but they both validate an xml where id is not unique.

Comment: @johankr Hmm I don't know then, but I'm not too familiar with `key`s. I'd suggest trying with a fully qualified XPath (`level2/id` I guess) to see if it fixes the issue.